# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'row'

Tags: python, list

Following Code From the book deep learning and the game of go 
Not Sure Why I am getting this error

full error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "bot_v_bot.py", line 25, in
>   
>       main()   File "bot_v_bot.py", line 20, in main
>       bot_move = bots[game.next_player].select_move(game)   File "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\books\pdf\code\Go ML\dlgo\agent\naive.py", line
>   14, in select_move
>       if game_state.is_valid_move(Move.play(canidate)) and not is_point_an_eye(game_state.board, canidate, game_state.next_player):
>   File "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\books\pdf\code\Go
>   ML\dlgo\agent\helpers.py", line 20, in is_point_an_eye
>       if board.is_on_grid(corners):   File "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\books\pdf\code\Go ML\dlgo\goboard_slow.py", line
>   71, in is_on_grid
>       return 1 <= point.row <= self.num_rows and 1 <= point.col <= 
>   self.num_cols AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'row'

**My Directory looks like**

```
GO ML
-bot_v_bot.py
-dlgo
---__pychache__

---agent
----__init__.py
----base.py
----helpers.py
----naive.py

---__init__.py
---goboard_slow.py
---gotypes.py
---utils.py
```

Bot_V_Bot code

```
from dlgo.agent import naive
from dlgo import goboard_slow
from dlgo import gotypes

from dlgo.utils import print_board, print_move
import time

def main():
    board_size = 9
    game = goboard_slow.GameState.new_game(board_size)
    bots = {
        gotypes.Player.black: naive.RandomBot(),
        gotypes.Player.white: naive.RandomBot(),
    }
    while not game.is_over():
        time.sleep(0.3)

        print(chr(27) + "[2j")
        print_board(game.board)
        bot_move = bots[game.next_player].select_move(game)
        print_move(game.next_player, bot_move)
        game = game.apply_move(bot_move)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

goboard_slow code

```
import copy

from dlgo.gotypes import Player
from dlgo.gotypes import Point

class GoString():
     def __init__(self, color, stones, liberties):
        self.color = color
        self.stones = set(stones)
        self.liberties = set(liberties)

    def remove_liberty(self, point):
        self.liberties.remove(point)

    def add_liberty(self, point):
        self.liberties.add(point)

    def merged_with(self, go_string):
        assert go_string.color == self.color
        combined_stones = self.stones | go_string.stones
        return GoString(
                self.color,
                combined_stones,
                (self.liberties | go_string.liberties) - combined_stones)
    @property
    def num_liberties(self):
        return len(self.liberties)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, GoString) and \
        self.color == other.color and \
        self.stones == other.stones and \
        self.liberties == other.liberties

class Board():
    def __init__(self, num_rows, num_cols):
        self.num_rows = num_rows
        self.num_cols = num_cols
        self._grid = {}

    def place_stone(self, player, point):
        assert self.is_on_grid(point)
        assert self._grid.get(point) is None
        adjacent_same_color = []
        adjacent_opposite_color = []
        liberties = []
        for neighbor in point.neighbors():
            if not self.is_on_grid(neighbor):
                continue
            neighbor_string = self._grid.get(neighbor)
            if neighbor_string is None:
                liberties.append(neighbor)
            elif neighbor_string.color == player:
                if neighbor_string not in adjacent_same_color:
                    adjacent_same_color.append(neighbor_string)
            else:
                if neighbor_string not in adjacent_opposite_color:
                    adjacent_opposite_color.append(neighbor_string)
        new_string = GoString(player, [point], liberties)
        for same_color_string in adjacent_same_color:
            new_string = new_string.merged_with(same_color_string)
        for new_string_point in new_string.stones:
            self._grid[new_string_point] = new_string
        for other_color_string in adjacent_opposite_color:
            other_color_string.remove_liberty(point)
        for other_color_string in adjacent_same_color:
            if other_color_string.num_liberties == 0:
                self._remove_string(other_color_string)

    def is_on_grid(self, point):
        return 1 <= point.row <= self.num_rows and 1 <= point.col <= self.num_cols

    def get(self, point):
        string = self._grid.get(point)
        if string is None:
            return None
        return string.color

    def get_go_string(self, point):
        string = self._grid.get(point)
        if string is None:
            return None
        return string 

    def _remove_string(self, string):
        for point in string.stones:
            for neighbor in point.neighbors():
                neighbor_string = self._grid.get(neighbor)
                if neighbor_string is None:
                    continue
                if neighbor_string is not string:
                    neighbor_string.add_liberty(point)
            self._grid[point] = None

class Move():
    def __init__(self, point=None, is_pass=False, is_resign=False):
        assert (point is not None) ^ is_pass ^ is_resign
        self.point = point
        self.is_play = (self.point is not None)
        self.is_pass = is_pass
        self.is_resign = is_resign

    @classmethod
    def play(cls, point):
        return Move(point=point)

    @classmethod
    def pass_turn(cls):
        return Move(is_pass=True)

    @classmethod
    def resign(cls):
        return Move(is_resign=True)


class GameState():
    def __init__(self, board, next_player, previous, move):
        self.board = board
        self.next_player = next_player
        self.previous_state = previous
        self.last_move = move

    def apply_move(self, move):
        if move.is_play:
            next_board = copy.deepcopy(self.board)
            next_board.place_stone(self.next_player, move.point)
        else:
            next_board = self.board
        return GameState(next_board, self.next_player.other, self, move)

    @classmethod
    def new_game(cls, board_size):
        if isinstance(board_size, int):
            board_size = (board_size, board_size)
        board = Board(*board_size)
        return GameState(board, Player.black, None, None)

    def is_over(self):
        if self.last_move is None:
            return False
        if self.last_move.is_resign:
            return True
        second_last_move = self.previous_state.last_move
        if second_last_move is None:
            return False
        return self.last_move.is_pass and second_last_move.is_pass

    def is_move_self_capture(self, Player, move):
        if not move.is_play:
            return False
        next_board = copy.deepcopy(self.board)
        next_board.place_stone(Player, move.point)
        new_string = next_board.get_go_string(move.point)
        return new_string.num_liberties == 0

    @property
    def situation(self):
        return (self.next_player, self.board)

    def does_move_validate_ko(self, player, move):
        if not move.is_play:
            return False
        next_board = copy.deepcopy(self.board)
        next_board.place_stone(player, move.point)
        next_situation = (Player.other, next_board)
        past_state = self.previous_state
        while past_state is not None:
            if past_state.situation == next_situation:
                return True
            past_state = past_state.previous_state
        return False

    def is_valid_move(self, move):
        if self.is_over():
            return False
        if move.is_pass or move.is_resign:
            return True
        return (
            self.board.get(move.point) is None and
            not self.is_move_self_capture(self.next_player, move) and
            not self.does_move_validate_ko(self.next_player, move))
```

**gotypes code**

```
import enum

from collections import namedtuple

class Player(enum.Enum):
    black = 1
    white = 2
    @property
    def other(self):
        return Player.black if self == Player.white else Player.white

class Point(namedtuple('Point', 'row col')):
    def neighbors(self):
        return [
            Point(self.row - 1, self.col),
            Point(self.row + 1, self.col),
            Point(self.row, self.col - 1),
            Point(self.row, self.col + 1),
        ]
```

**utils code**

```
import random 
from dlgo.agent.base import Agent
from dlgo.agent.helpers import is_point_an_eye
from dlgo.goboard_slow import Move
from dlgo.gotypes import Point 

class RandomBot(Agent):
    def select_move(self, game_state):
        """"Choose a random valid move that preserves our own eyes."""
        canidates = []
        for r in range(1, game_state.board.num_rows + 1):
            for c in range(1, game_state.board.num_cols +1):
                canidate = Point(row=r, col=c)
                if game_state.is_valid_move(Move.play(canidate)) and not is_point_an_eye(game_state.board, canidate, game_state.next_player):
                    canidates.append(canidate)
        if not canidates:
            return Move.pass_turn()
        return Move.play(random.choice(canidates))


    from dlgo import gotypes

    COLS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST'
    STONE_TO_CHAR = {
        None: ' . ',
        gotypes.Player.black: ' x ',
        gotypes.Player.white: ' o ',
    }

    def print_move(player, move):
        if move.is_pass:
            move_str = 'passes'
        elif move.is_resign:
            move_str = 'resigns'
        else:
            move_str = '%s%d' % (COLS[move.point.col - 1], move.point.row)
        print('%s %s' % (player, move_str))

    def print_board(board):
        for row in range(board.num_rows, 0, -1):
            bump = " " if row <= 9 else ""
            line = []
            for col in range(1, board.num_cols + 1):
                stone = board.get(gotypes.Point(row = row, col = col))
                line.append(STONE_TO_CHAR[stone])
            print('%s%d %s' % (bump, row, ''.join(line)))
        print('   ' + '  '.join(COLS[:board.num_cols]))
```

**Helpers Code**

```
from dlgo.gotypes import Point

def is_point_an_eye(board, point, color):
    if board.get(point) is not None:
        return False
    for neighbor in point.neighbors():
        if board.is_on_grid(neighbor):
            neighbor_color= board.get(neighbor)
            if neighbor_color != color:
                return False
    friendly_corners = 0
    off_board_corners = 0
    corners = [
        Point(point.row - 1, point.col - 1),
        Point(point.row - 1, point.col + 1),
        Point(point.row + 1, point.col - 1),
        Point(point.row + 1, point.col + 1),
    ]
    for corner in corners:
        if board.is_on_grid(corners):
            corner_color = board.get(corner)
            if corner_color == olor:
                friendly_corners += 1
        else:
            off_board_corners += 1
    if off_board_corners > 0:
        return off_board_corners + friendly_corners == 4
    return friendly_corners >= 3
```

**Base Code**

```
class Agent:
    def __init(self):
        pass
    def selec_move(self, game_state):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

**Both Inits are empty**

Comment: `point` is a list. What is `point.row` supposed to be? I don't see any classes in your posted code with a `row` attribute.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
You haven't taken the trouble to print the critical variables at point of failure, and you haven't included the code needed to reproduce or trace the problem.  You've also included a *lot* of code that doesn't contribute.  Please reduce this to a MRE.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].row` would produce an error similar to yours. This is because it is illegal to write `.row` immediately after a list. Likewise, the following is also illegal:            `x = ['a', 'b', 'c']         print(x.row)`

Comment: @Barmar Does that updated code help?

Comment: @Prune is that what i needed?

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon I am not sure how to fix that or change it from my code

Comment: I think it's just a typo: `board.is_on_grid(corners)` should be `board.is_on_grid(corner)`

Comment: `corners` is the list of all corner points, `corner` is the current element in the `for` loop.

Comment: No, that's not what I suggested.  Please re-read my posting and the given link before asking another question; they will help you focus your request.  My down-votes here remain: you posted at least 100 lines of code and no tracing, for a problem involving two variables and much less code to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

> `corners` is the list of all `corner` points, corner is 
>   the current element in the `for` loop.
>   **Barmar**
>
> I think it's just a typo: board.is_on_grid(corners) 
>   should be board.is_on_grid(corner)
>   **Barmar**

These worked and fixed it